# kotlin command line compiler

Tags: kotlin

How do I use the js command line compiler?

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit { 
    println("Hello world!") 
}

E:\kotlinc\bin>kotlinc-js -output test -sourceFiles test.kt
ERROR: E:\kotlinc\bin\test.kt: (4, 5) Unresolved reference: println
exec() finished with COMPILATION_ERROR return code
```

In the IDE I couldn't get js compilation to work either. Is there an up to date getting started guide for IntelliJ IDEA 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a path to the library (kotlin-jslib.jar), use `-libraryFiles` command line option

Comment: Documentation for the command-line compiler is at: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html