# "ERROR: Unresolved reference: Thread in Eclipse IDE"

Tags: java, eclipse, kotlin, runtime-error

I'm having a weird error using Kotlin with **Eclipse IDE** (Oxygen + Kotlin plugin 0.8.6 + **Java 10.0.2**).

While it's able to compile the code shown here:

```
package com.test

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Thread.currentThread()
    println("hello")
}
```

It always fails executing inside Eclipse (in fact I think it fails while trying to compile) it with following error:

```
/<path>/src/com/test/Test1.kt
    ERROR: Unresolved reference: Thread (6, 5)
```

And, it works properly if the same is done in Intellij IDEA. But I would like keep using Eclipse.

Any thoughts about what could be happening?

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in my case I'm using Eclipse, not IntelliJ, because the rest of my projects are there and I wanted to start moving parts to kotlin

Comment: ...But you gave me an idea, so I reviewed the classpath and saw that the project was using classpath (Kotlin) and modulepath (JRE for Java 10)... 

Doing some tests/changes I stumbled upon the fact that it was  the Java 10 JRE what it didn't like... 

I changed it to Java 8 JRE and now it works (and it moved to a classpath library and doesn't appear as modulepath anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following S.K. advice I read the suggested post about IntelliJ problem. Even though mine was related to using Eclipse, it gave me a clue to test.

So I reviewed the classpath and saw that the project was using both a classpath (Kotlin) and a modulepath (JRE for Java 10)... Doing some tests/changes I stumbled upon the fact that it was the Java 10 JRE what it didn't like...

I changed project'sJRE to Java 8 JRE and now it works (and it moved to a classpath library and doesn't appear as modulepath anymore).

The Kotlin Eclipse plugin doesn't work with Java 10 yet.

Thanks