# Unresolved reference,Cannot access class

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using android studio 3.2.1 and Kotlin 1.2.71

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

 classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.2.71'
```

for almost time whenever I build project getting below errors with respect to Kotlin classes name and object references

Eg: class DelUserIP

```
Unresolved reference: DelUserIP
: Cannot access class ‘input.DelUserIP’. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
```

but after an error, if I build project once again it will be success build without error after some build again I am experiencing same above error…

Comment: Hey @ask, please check this answer. Hope it solves the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34625454/4491971

Comment: @MohitAjwani I am using both kotlin android studio latest and stable version after getting above mentioned error rebuild project its working fine but again and again i am experiencing same  issue...

Comment: Do you have a multi-module project?

Comment: @ask I had similar issues when JVM that intelij was using (JDK 9) missmatched with jdk that kotlin was using (JDK 8)... Try check if those are equal as they should.

Comment: @yole don't had multi-module..

Comment: @UrošJarc using  jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: @ask And your kotlin compiler: `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Kotlin Compiler` ?

Comment: @UrošJarc  inside `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler` i didn't found  kotlin compiler but inside 
`File | Settings | Other Settings | Kotlin Compiler` language version ,API version is- latest stable 1.2

Comment: @ask `File | Settings | Other Settings | Kotlin Compiler` Oh I'm sorry I was looking on intelij...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182034/discussion-between-ask-and-uros-jarc).

Answer (score 0):

after renaming my package name of data classes from name  "module" to some other name,then i didn't experienced  issue again.