# Unresolved Dependency on package in subproject

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my Kotlin spring boot project, I am using Kotlin DSL Gradle, with three subprojects.  Two of which are `security` which depends on `database`.

In IntelliJ, the application runs successfully and performs as expected (when run as a Spring Boot application run config).

However, when I try to build the project with Gradle `./gradlew clean build` I get

```
e: /security/src/main/kotlin/com/path/security/jwt/JwtRealm.kt: (3, 26): Unresolved reference: database
e: /security/src/main/kotlin/com/path/security/jwt/JwtRealm.kt: (19, 24): Unresolved reference: UsersRepository
e: /security/src/main/kotlin/com/path/security/jwt/JwtRealm.kt: (36, 48): Unresolved reference: it
e: /security/src/main/kotlin/com/path/security/jwt/JwtRealm.kt: (38, 42): Unresolved reference: it
e: /security/src/main/kotlin/com/path/security/jwt/JwtRealm.kt: (38, 75): Unresolved reference: it
e: /security/src/main/kotlin/com/path/security/jwt/JwtRealm.kt: (40, 63): Unresolved reference: it
> Task :security:compileKotlin FAILED
```

The actual line it is complaining about is:

```
import com.path.database.repositories.UsersRepository
```

The `it` error are values from the repo.  The `UserRepository` class is in the module `database` and the `JwtRealm` is in the `security` module.

My `build.gradle.kts` file in the `security` module looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

group = "com.path"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") 
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.noarg") 
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") 
    id("org.springframework.boot")
    id("io.spring.dependency-management")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation(kotlin("reflect"))

    implementation(project(":database"))

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.1.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:2.1.1.RELEASE")

    implementation("org.apache.shiro:shiro-spring-boot-web-starter:1.4.0")
    implementation("com.h2database:h2:1.4.197")
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:3.4.1")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.6.22")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
}
```

Which is basically the same as my root project Gradle files, only that also contains references to all the subprojects (or modules).  I've also listed all the subprojects in the `settings.gradle.kts`

IntelliJ has no problem running, or browsing this code, there are no highlighted errors or warnings.

I have an `@Configuration` annotated class as the root of each module with `@ComponentScan` annotation also.

What am I missing?

Comment: IntelliJ by default uses its own build system. You can get it to use Gradle instead: `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Runner -> Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle`. The dependencies can be set up in IntelliJ independently from Gradle (though that's not a good idea). That's why it works with one and not the other. If you open the Gradle window in IntelliJ and expand the node for the "security" project, you should see its dependencies. Can you see "database" in there? Is it highlighted red? That'll show whether Gradle can see it as a dependency or not.

Comment: Yes, the Gradle tab shows the dependencies are all happy.  `security` does indeed depend on `database` with no red squiglies.  Running the build from the tab does also, naturally, fail.

Comment: Does running `./gradlew dependencies` show the dependencies to be the way you expect? Also, do you have any custom source sets or anything like that?

Comment: Yep, dependencies are exactly as expected. I'll update later with them. Nope, I've nothing complicated or unusual in my set up, no custom source sets.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After a lot of digging I found that this was a Spring Boot issue.  I fixed this by applying

```
bootJar.enabled = false  
jar.enabled = true
```

to each of the subprojects.  In KotlinDSL this is:

```
tasks.withType<BootJar> {
    enabled = false
}
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    enabled = true
}
```

I hope this helps someone else, as I only found this issue after a lot of digging.  Source of the solution is here: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/393

Comment: You cannot even *imagine* how much time I've wasted trying to find this very solution... thanks.

Comment: I've spent about 12 hrs banging my head, and was about to give up on Kotlin because of this. Thank you!