# Maven not picking up the classes from dependency modules

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices

In my `spring-boot` project there are two microservices, one config-server, and one naming server. It also has two modules which I am adding as a dependency in the microservices.

Below is the `pom` of the `commons-new` module which should be a dependency in my microservices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.highpeak.tlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-new</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>commons-new</name>
    <description>Contains common modules needed by all the microservices</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And I am adding it as a dependency in my microservice.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.highpeak.tlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>ybanq-auth-manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ybanq-auth-manager</name>
    <description>Manages the authentication process with ybanq</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.testSource>1.8</maven.compiler.testSource>
        <maven.compiler.testTarget>1.8</maven.compiler.testTarget>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.highpeak.tlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-new</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.highpeak.tlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>redis-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I try to build the microservice using the command `mvn clean install`, it is throwing `compiler-error` message.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project ybanq-auth-manager: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /Users/sandeshaj/Documents/Bitbucket/lawshram-payments/ybanq-auth-manager/src/main/java/com/highpeak/tlp/ybanqauthmanager/controller/AuthController.java:[3,42] package com.highpeak.tlp.commons.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sandeshaj/Documents/Bitbucket/lawshram-payments/ybanq-auth-manager/src/main/java/com/highpeak/tlp/ybanqauthmanager/controller/AuthController.java:[4,37] package com.highpeak.tlp.commons.util does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sandeshaj/Documents/Bitbucket/lawshram-payments/ybanq-auth-manager/src/main/java/com/highpeak/tlp/ybanqauthmanager/service/AuthManagerService.java:[3,42] package com.highpeak.tlp.commons.exception does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/sandeshaj/Documents/Bitbucket/lawshram-payments/ybanq-auth-manager/src/main/java/com/highpeak/tlp/ybanqauthmanager/service/AuthManagerService.java:[11,51] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class DataException
[ERROR]   location: interface com.highpeak.tlp.ybanqauthmanager.service.AuthManagerService
[ERROR] /Users/sandeshaj/Documents/Bitbucket/lawshram-payments/ybanq-auth-manager/src/main/java/com/highpeak/tlp/ybanqauthmanager/service/AuthManagerServiceImpl.java:[19,42] package com.highpeak.tlp.commons.exception does not exist
```

However, in IntelliJ editor those classes are accessible and Intellij is not showing the compiler error. But when I run the app in IntelliJ, it shows the same errors.

What is the mistake I am making? Since I added the module as dependency their classes should be available, right?

My system maven version is `3.5.4`.

Comment: You should use the command `mvn clean install` again for `commons-new`. I think that it's a previous library in your .m2 repository. Then, try again `mvn clean install` with your microservice module

Comment: I did that multiple times. No luck

Comment: Can you open `commons-new` jar of your .m2 and check if there are the packages needed?

Comment: Yes. It is correct

Comment: can you try to remove spring boot plugin from common-new?

Comment: After removing it, it worked!!!. What was the issue? Can you please answer @kqr

Comment: @kqr Please answer the question with explanation when you get some time

Comment: You can remove all lines `<scope>compile</scope>` ,  because scope `compile` is default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Boot plugin package up all dependency jars and pulls them into the jar your module builds. The structure of this jar is specifically for Spring Boot runnable applications and is not compatible with the normal jar structures, so you can't use a Spring Boot Application jar as maven dependency jar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove spring boot plugin from submodule (common-new).
I had similar issue, but with gradle and found this [Unresolved Dependency on package in subproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775262/unresolved-dependency-on-package-in-subproject)

Unfortunately, I don't know what is exact issue in "using" spring boot plugin in submodules/subprojects.

Comment: Spring Boot plugin creates a runnable jar that is more like an ear or war.  If you unzip the spring boot jar you will see how it is different from a simple library jar.

Comment: Thx. I thought so