# Kotlin read property annotation via reflection

Tags: kotlin, reflection, properties, annotations

I've created an annotation for properties and now I want to read it via reflection at runtime. In my opinion I'm doing everything right but there's no annotation.

Why isn't the annotation not available?

```
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)
annotation class MyAnnotation

class MyClass(@MyAnnotation val attr: List<String>)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var prop = MyClass::attr
    prop.annotations.forEach { println("prop.annotations -> " + it) }
    prop.javaClass.getAnnotations().forEach { println("prop.javaClass.getAnnotations -> " + it) }
    println("isAnnotationPresent -> ${prop.javaClass.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation::class.java)}")
}
```

**Output:**
*prop.javaClass.getAnnotations -> @kotlin.Metadata(xi=0, bv=[1, 0, 3], mv=[1, 1, 16], k=3, xs=, d1=[], d2=[], pn=)
isAnnotationPresent -> false*

Comment: Do you have any specific reason for using VALUE_PARAMETER target?

Comment: You're right. Without the target VALUE_PARAMETER the annotation appears in the annotations list. Why?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of having the annotation target specified as `@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER)`, you can specify it as `@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)` and access it as below:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD)
annotation class MyAnnotation

class MyClass(@MyAnnotation val attr: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val prop = MyClass::attr
    println("Is MyAnnotation annotated - ${prop.javaField?.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation::class.java)}")
    prop.javaField?.annotations?.forEach { println("Annotation present is - ${it.annotationClass.qualifiedName}") }
}
```

The output:

> Is MyAnnotation annotated - true
>
> Annotation present is - packageName.MyAnnotation

Comment: Does this help @Jayser ?

Comment: I had to replaced javaField with javaClass but it didn't work.

Comment: @Jayser no you shouldn't use `javaClass`, but use `javaField` as specified in my answer. The code snippet that is part of my answer works fine. Please try that.

Comment: I use Kotlin 1.3.61 and I get an compile time error of "Unresolved reference: javaField"

Comment: kotlin-reflect is also added to my maven dependencies. I don't why the javaField Property isn't available.

Comment: @Jayser that might be an environment issue, as `javaField` is from kotlin-reflect itself. Can you try the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij/53063096)?

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets)

> If you don't specify a use-site target, the target is chosen according to the @Target annotation of the annotation being used. If there are multiple applicable targets, the first applicable target from the following list is used:
>
> - param;
> - property;
> - field.

So in your case it's the parameter which is annotated, not the property. Depending on your requirements, you could work around it by checking both property and parameter annotations:

```
val param = MyClass::class.primaryConstructor.findParameterByName(prop.name)
val annotations = prop.annotations + (param?.annotations ?: listOf())
```