# Unresolved reference : isInitialized on lateinit property

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I would like to use the isInitialized method on a lateinit property, but I can't because the compiler underlines in red with the error "Unresolved reference"

Here is the code :

```java
class MainViewModel: ViewModel()
{
    lateinit var myData: MutableLiveData<Data>

    fun getData() {
        if (this::myData.isInitialized)
    }
}
```

I can't go any further because of that error...

Here is my gradle files :

**project.gradle:**

```
kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**app gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.2.0"
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine from my end. Which class do you have the code?

Comment: ViewModel class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin unresolved reference in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to review your dependencies whether they correspond:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
kapt 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
```

The `compiler` is very necessary.