# maxBy((Map.Entry<K, V>) -> R): Map.Entry<K, V>?' is deprecated. Use maxByOrNull instead

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to use maxBy in kotlin but I get a deprecated warning to replace it with maxByOrNull.

```
val max = response.maxBy { it.value.size }
```

> maxBy((Map.Entry<K, V>) -> R): Map.Entry<K, V>?' is deprecated. Use maxByOrNull instead.

The autofix in android studio does it like below

```
val max = maxByOrNull({ it.value.size })
```

But this doesn't compile with error

> Unresolved reference: maxByOrNull

What is the proper implementation as `response.maxByOrNull { it.value.size }` also doesn't work

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij

Comment: You need to call it on ``response``, same as your original ``maxBy`` version. If it's still not working (highlighted in red) put the text cursor on it, hit alt+enter and pick the import option