# Can't get kotlin "hello world" example to Run in intelliJ

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm following the intelliJ IDEA tutorial titled [Create your first Kotlin application
(Last modified: 08 March 2021)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-your-first-kotlin-app.html).  Here are the various versions I'm using:

```
~$ java -version
java version "16" 2021-03-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16+36-2231)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16+36-2231, mixed mode, sharing)

~$ javac -version
javac 16
```

---

[image: jdk version]

[image: intelliJ version]

[image: kotlin version]

Here's my code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("What is your name?")
    val name = readLine()
    println("Hello $name")
}
```

Here's what my project structure looks like:

[image]

I notice that it says "Kotlin not configured" above my code, but when I go to `Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin in Project`, I get

[image: kotlin config]:

In the Event Log pane, I see this:

```
4/15/21
1:54 PM Download pre-built shared indexes
                Reduce the indexing time and CPU load with pre-built JDK shared indexes
                Always download
                Download once
                Don't show again
                Configure...

1:54 PM Gradle sync started

1:54 PM Gradle sync failed: Unsupported class file major version 60 (5 s 329 ms)

1:55 PM No IDE or plugin updates available
```

In the Problems(?) pane, I see this:

```
Unresolved reference: println
Unresolved reference: readLine
Unresolved reference: println
Parameter 'args' is never used
Package directive doesn't match file location
```

Any ideas on why the basic functions in my program are not recognized?

Thanks for looking!

Edit: I tried downloading JDK 15 and specifying that in my Project Structure, but I got the same results:

[image: jdk version]

[image]

Comment: Try looking into this question. [Kotlin unresolved reference in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij)

Comment: @UmarzzstuSyed, I looked at the answers there before posting my question.  I tried some things, didn't understand other things.

Comment: Check your Kotlin compiler version from `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Kotlin Compiler`. After that check Kotlin version from `build.gradle.kts` file.

Comment: @Furkan, I can't find `Build, Execution, Deployment` anywhere.

Comment: @Furkan, Okay, I found it under `intelliJ IDEA > Preferences`. For the Kotlin compiler: `Language version: Latest stable(1.4)`, `API version: Latest stable(1.4)`.  I installed everything yesterday, so all software should be the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it working.  I'll try to figure out what I did.

tldr;  I had to switch from `JDK 16` to `JDK 15` to get my hello world console application to run.

First, when I was setting up the project, I chose the wrong Project Template: I selected `JVM - Application` rather than `JVM - Console Application`. This is what I needed to do:

[image]

So, I started a new project, chose the right template, and I typed in my code, and I noticed a `Build` pane at the bottom left displayed:

[image]

I tried `Build > Build Project`, and nothing changed.  So, I tried the `Run` menu item: the first section of the Run menu was grayed out, but there was another Run command in the second section of the Run menu. I selected that Run, and a little window popped up with the following:

```
      Run
  0  Edit Configurations
```

The "0 Edit Configurations" line was highlighted, and I got nowhere trying to figure out how to Run my code.

So, I started yet another new project, and this time I selected a different JDK, version 15:

[image]

After clicking `Next`, then `Finish`, I typed in my code, and this time the Build pane looked like the following (without me doing anything but typing in my code):

[image]

After I finished typing in my code, as the tutorial described, this time there was a little green arrow in the gutter:

[image]

When I clicked on the green arrow in the gutter, I could successfully Run my program.

So, it appears that you cannot use `JDK 16`, and you have to use `JDK 15`.  intelliJ was able to detect all my installed Java versions, so any version you have installed should appear as a choice in the the project settings.  You may have to quit intelliJ, then restart intelliJ after you install JDK 15 in order to see it listed as a choice under `Project JDK:` when you create a project.

Comment: Yes, JDK 16 will be supported since Kotlin 1.5: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45566

Answer (score 0):

try build>clean project.
As for your unresolved references, you can double-click/left-click > show context options. If that doesn't work then maybe reinstall InteliJ Idea or download Android Studio which has a lot more support on google and yt.

Comment: Neither of those exist.