# Why is the code giving me an unresolved reference when I imported the file and the function is there?

Tags: android, kotlin, aws-amplify

I'm working with AWS Amplify + Android Studio. In the `backend.kt` file, I call `UserData.setSignedIn` which gives me a `Unresolved reference: setSignedIn` error. I imported the file where this function is but it still gives me that error. Here are the two files:

```
package com.wcsng.dlocapp

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.service.autofill.UserData
import android.util.Log
import com.amplifyframework.AmplifyException
import com.amplifyframework.api.aws.AWSApiPlugin
import com.amplifyframework.auth.AuthChannelEventName
import com.amplifyframework.auth.AuthException
import com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthPlugin
import com.amplifyframework.auth.cognito.AWSCognitoAuthSession
import com.amplifyframework.auth.result.AuthSessionResult
import com.amplifyframework.auth.result.AuthSignInResult
import com.amplifyframework.core.Amplify
import com.amplifyframework.core.InitializationStatus
import com.amplifyframework.hub.HubChannel
import com.amplifyframework.hub.HubEvent
import com.wcsng.dlocapp.UserData.setSignedIn

object Backend {

    private const val TAG = "Backend"

    fun initialize(applicationContext: Context) : Backend {
        try {
            Amplify.addPlugin(AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
            Amplify.addPlugin(AWSApiPlugin())
            Amplify.configure(applicationContext)
            Log.i(TAG, "Initialized Amplify")
        } catch (e: AmplifyException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not initialize Amplify", e)
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "registering hub event")

        // listen to auth event
        Amplify.Hub.subscribe(HubChannel.AUTH) { hubEvent: HubEvent<*> ->

            when (hubEvent.name) {
                InitializationStatus.SUCCEEDED.toString() -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Amplify successfully initialized")
                }
                InitializationStatus.FAILED.toString() -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Amplify initialization failed")
                }
                else -> {
                    when (AuthChannelEventName.valueOf(hubEvent.name)) {
                        AuthChannelEventName.SIGNED_IN -> {
                            updateUserData(true)
                            Log.i(TAG, "HUB : SIGNED_IN")
                        }
                        AuthChannelEventName.SIGNED_OUT -> {
                            updateUserData(false)
                            Log.i(TAG, "HUB : SIGNED_OUT")
                        }
                        else -> Log.i(TAG, """HUB EVENT:${hubEvent.name}""")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "retrieving session status")

        // is user already authenticated (from a previous execution) ?
        Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession(
            { result ->
                Log.i(TAG, result.toString())
                val cognitoAuthSession = result as AWSCognitoAuthSession
                // update UI
                this.updateUserData(cognitoAuthSession.isSignedIn)
                when (cognitoAuthSession.identityId.type) {
                    AuthSessionResult.Type.SUCCESS ->  Log.i(TAG, "IdentityId: " + cognitoAuthSession.identityId.value)
                    AuthSessionResult.Type.FAILURE -> Log.i(TAG, "IdentityId not present because: " + cognitoAuthSession.identityId.error.toString())
                }
            },
            { error -> Log.i(TAG, error.toString()) }
        )

        return this
    }

    private fun updateUserData(withSignedInStatus : Boolean) {
        UserData.setSignedIn(withSignedInStatus) // ERROR IS HERE
    }

    fun signOut() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Initiate Signout Sequence")

        Amplify.Auth.signOut(
            { Log.i(TAG, "Signed out!") },
            { error -> Log.e(TAG, error.toString()) }
        )
    }

    fun signIn(callingActivity: Activity) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Initiate Signin Sequence")

        Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(
            callingActivity,
            { result: AuthSignInResult ->  Log.i(TAG, result.toString()) },
            { error: AuthException -> Log.e(TAG, error.toString()) }
        )
    }

    // Backend.kt
    // pass the data from web redirect to Amplify libs
    fun handleWebUISignInResponse(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "received requestCode : $requestCode and resultCode : $resultCode")
        if (requestCode == AWSCognitoAuthPlugin.WEB_UI_SIGN_IN_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
            Amplify.Auth.handleWebUISignInResponse(data)
        }
    }

}
```

```
package com.wcsng.dlocapp

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.location.Location
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import com.amplifyframework.datastore.generated.model.LocationData

// a singleton to hold user data (this is a ViewModel pattern, without inheriting from ViewModel)
object UserData {

    private const val TAG = "UserData"

    //
    // observable properties
    //

    // signed in status
    private val _isSignedIn = MutableLiveData<Boolean>(false)
    var isSignedIn: LiveData<Boolean> = _isSignedIn

    fun setSignedIn(newValue : Boolean) {
        // use postvalue() to make the assignation on the main (UI) thread
        _isSignedIn.postValue(newValue)
    }


    // a note
    data class Location(val id: String, val name: String, val map: String, var location: String) {
        override fun toString(): String = name

        // return an API NoteData from this Note object
        val data : LocationData?
            get() = LocationData.builder()
                .name(this.name)
                .id(this.id)
                .map(this.map)
                .location(this.location)
                .build()


        // static function to create a Note from a NoteData API object
        companion object {
            fun from(locationData : LocationData) : Location {
                val result = Location(locationData.id, locationData.name, locationData.map, locationData.location)

                return result
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you try rebuilding your project after cleaning, Android Studio sometimes behaves weirdly and this most probably fixes it

Comment: I just did that and nothing changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij

Comment: It is just some weird Kotlin issue, try upgrading Kotlin plugin version, Gradle version and check compatibility of your AWSAmplify SDK with Kotlin, I mean the versions

Comment: Thanks! There was a conflicting import so it's fixed now.

Comment: @kanishka can you please share you fix as i am also getting the same issue