# I get an error when i try to run my first kotlin code in intellij idea community version 2021.2

Tags: kotlin

This is the error code

```
 error: unresolved reference: string (myfirstfile.kts:1:22)
```

myfirstfile.kts:1:22: error: unresolved reference: string

```
fun main(args: Array<string>) {
                     ^ww33
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin unresolved reference in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712046/kotlin-unresolved-reference-in-intellij)

Comment: Did you try writing the name of the "String" class starting with the big S ?
I think, in Kotlin class names are case sensitive

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing because it looks like you modified your code before pasting it here, because the error doesn't match what you're showing.

I'm guessing you had

```
fun main(args: Array<string>) {
```

and that doesn't work because there is no class named `string`. It's named `String` with a capital S. By convention, all class names start with capital letters. (It's possible to define a class name without an initial capital letter, but no one does this because it makes your code hard to read.) It should look like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
```