# Unresolved reference: java, unresolved reference lazy, unresolved reference with

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-reflect

Last time I did this the project ran just fine but I am getting these errors now, I tried installing kotlin-reflect but still it didn't work.
It doesn't recognise lazy and with either and I simply don't know what to do anymore.
**Lazy and ::class.java unresolved references**

```
package io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.ui

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.utils.CustomViewModelFactory
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_first.*

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the default destination in the navigation.
 */
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: FragmentOrActivityViewModel by lazy {
        val factory = CustomViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application)
        ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(FragmentOrActivityViewModel::class.java)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //With kotlinx we replace by button_first.setOnClickListener {
        // }
        //view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_first).setOnClickListener {
         //   findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        //}
    }
    private fun fetchData() {
        //viewModel.fetchPOJORetrofitResponses
    }
    private fun setUpObservers() {
        fetchData()
        //viewModel.getPOJORetrofitResponses().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        //   when(it.status) {
        //      Status.SUCCESS -> {
        //          we fill our POJORetrofitResponseItemViewModel array by setting it to it.data then we modify the ui
        //          then we set the elements of our recyclerview adapter
        //          and set the recyclerview adapter here
        //      }
        //      Status.LOADING -> {
        //
        //      }
        //      Status.ERROR -> {
        //
        //      }
        //   }
        //
        // })
    }
}
```

***with* and ::class.java unresolved references**

```
package io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.utils

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.repository.local.LocalHelper
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.repository.local.LocalHelperImpl
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.repository.remote.ApiHelper
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.repository.remote.ApiHelperImpl
import io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture.ui.FragmentOrActivityViewModel

import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
//@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class CustomViewModelFactory(private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
    private val apiHelper: ApiHelper = ApiHelperImpl()
    private val localHelper: LocalHelper = LocalHelperImpl(context = application.applicationContext)

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>) : T {
        return with(modelClass) {
            when {
                //We must add another choice we may have to add isAssignableFrom(viewModel::class.java)
                FragmentOrActivityViewModel::class.java -> FragmentOrActivityViewModel(application, apiHelper, localHelper)
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel")
            }
        } as T
    }
}
```

**Gradle file**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.keepcoding.mvvmarchitecture"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.10'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.0.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.6.20'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    // Gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // Glide
    implementation ("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0") {
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }

    // Coroutines

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"

    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0-alpha02"
}
```

Comment: try this ..https://stackoverflow.com/a/34625454/15597511

Comment: Hi what you mean is that the android studio and my kotlin versions don’t match? So I have to update both am I right?

Comment: yes ! if that doesnt fix it u have other ways by clearing the cache and cleaning the maven and reinstalling them